# "Top-align" a stack of items in an equation

Tags: equations, align, split

This should be simple to achieve, but I wasn't able to figure out how. I have an equation

```
\begin{equation}
    f=g\text{ text }\begin{split}&A\\&Bbb\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The goal is that "f = g text A" are in one line. However, with the solution above the split environment is vertically centered with respect to "f = g text". I've also tried `\substack` and the `align`-environment, but all of them are vertically centered in the same way and/or have `A` and `Bbb` not left-aligned (which is what I need).

Comment: Where should the equation number be placed: On the upper line, centered between the two lines, or on the lower line? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(My initial answer presented just an `aligned`-based solution. I've edited the answer to add an `array`-based solution.)

Instead of using a `split` environment, I suggest you use either an `aligned[t]` environment or an `array[t]` environment. The results of the two approaches are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

The line spacing provided by the `aligned`-based solution is, by design, a bit more generous than that of the `array`-based solution. Choose whichever approach best meets your spacing-related needs.

Observe that with either approach, the equation number is on the same baseline as the `f=g\text{ text }A` material.

The contents of `aligned` and `array` environments are processed in `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` math mode, respectively. Because "A" and "Bbb" are rather simple, there's no font size difference between the two approaches. If it's important that the contents of the `array` environment be processed in display-style math mode (while still enjoying the tighter line spacing), I suggest you change the `l` column specification to `>{\displaystyle}l`. Aside: This also requires loading the `array` package -- which you may already be doing in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    f=g\text{ text }\begin{aligned}[t]
                      &A\\
                      &Bbb
                    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    f=g\text{ text }\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                      A\\
                      Bbb
                    \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A new good year :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - A happy new year to you too! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you didn't think to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  f=g\text{ text } & A\\ & Bbb
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]